# Import OData dataset

Tags: r, odata

How do I properly download and load in R an `OData` dataset?

I tried the `OData` package, and even if the documentation is really simple, I am sure, I am missing something trivial.

I am trying to download and parse in R [this dataset](https://data.nasa.gov/Space-Science/Meteorite-Landings/gh4g-9sfh), but I cannot get how it is structured. Is it a XML format? Hence, what is the reason for a `separator` argument?

```
library(OData)
#What is the correct argument for the separator?
downloadResourceCsv("https://data.nasa.gov/OData.svc/gh4g-9sfh", sep = "")
```

Comment: While OData is an option, since you are having trouble with that, why not just download the csv file?

Comment: Well, mainly because it is easier to sinchronize it with the online dataset.

Comment: `RSocrata::read.socrata("https://data.nasa.gov/OData.svc/gh4g-9sfh")`

Answer (score 1):

As hrbrmstr suggests, use the RSocrata package
e.g., go to [1](http://httphttps://data.cdc.gov/NCHS/Provisional-COVID-19-Death-Counts-by-Sex-Age-and-S/9bhg-hcku), click on ... in the top right,
click on "Access this Dataset via OData", click
on "Copy" to copy the OData endpoint, save it:

```
url <- "https://data.cdc.gov/api/odata/v4/9bhg-hcku"
library(RSocrata)
dat <- read.socrata(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's XML format.So download first.

Try using **httr** package.

```
library(httr)
r <- GET("http://httpbin.org/get")
```

Visit [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html) site for quick-start.

After download use **XML** package for xmlParse.

Thank you

Comment: Why wld the OP do that when this is built-in functionality to RSocrata? and, why wld you use the `XML` package vs the `xml2` package? how will the OP deal with the default namespace in the resultant XML?

Comment: Because `RSocrata` doesn't appear to work for files outside the US. For example: try `open.statswales.gov.wales/en-gb/dataset/wimd1902`